# French word families

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

Does anyone know of a website or book on French language *word families*, something along the line of Howard Keller's [*German Word Family Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DzcC0_Clh18C&printsec=frontcover)?  I'm interested in French *word roots* and the verbs, adjectives, nouns, and adverbs that contain them, for my study of French vocabulary.  I've been googling away for a couple days, but can't seem to find anything fitting the bill.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the special book that fulfils your need.

**But**

> The majority of French words derive from *Vulgar Latin* or were constructed from *Latin* or *Greek* roots. In many cases a single etymological root appears in *French* in a "popular" or native form, inherited from *Vulgar Latin*, and a learned form, borrowed later from *Classical Latin*. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language#Vocabulary))

Looking in a *Latin/Greek* dictionary will help you to find *"root words"* in French.

Moreover, if you already know a Latin based language you can try to guess from its vocabulary.

For [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_grammar), French is part of [Romance languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages) from where you can get inspiration too.

---

EDIT : [wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/) often give the etymology of the word and how it was built.

Answer (score 0):

There's the famous [Dictionnaire historique de la langue française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_historique_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) by Alain Rey. An excellent reference, very useful, and it's quite exactly what you seem to search for.

It could be an expensive book (2 volumes in fact), but I guess it could also be found in some french (public or not) libraries.

Comment: Laure, I expect your full support on this one ! ;-) I saw you do many references to the book on this site, about various [subjects](http://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=alain+rey).

Answer (score 0):

Older material; nevertheless, these might provide some insight and are presented more or less in the format you alluded to:

> [*Dictionnaire des racines et derivés de la langue française, dans
>   lequel on trouve tous les mots distribués par famille d'après la
>   similitude de consonnance et de signification, et chaque famille
>   rangée dans l'ordre abécédaire de la racine dont elle dépend*](https://archive.org/stream/dictionnairedesr00char#page/n7/mode/2up),
>   Charrassin, Frédéric; François, Ferdinand, ed. Grassart, 1900
>
> [*Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue françoise, où les mots sont
>   classés par familles*](https://archive.org/stream/dictionnairetym01roqugoog#page/n9/mode/2up) ... Jean-Baptiste -Bonaventure de Roquefort,
>   ed. Decourchant, 1829, (also  [tome deuxième](https://archive.org/stream/dictionnairetym00roqugoog#page/n9/mode/2up))

Note such works often have "*par famille*" or "*par racines*" in their title. Also, something of a curiosity, along the same lines, in English:

> [*The Principal Roots of the French Language: Simplified by a Display
>   of Their Incorporation Into The English Tongue*](https://archive.org/stream/principalrootsf00hallgoog#page/n8/mode/2up), Hall's, publ.
>   John Taylor, 1826

Generally, see these [resources](http://www.lexilogos.com/francais_langue_dictionnaires.htm), including the etymology [section](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/) of the *TLFi*, and this [etymology](http://www.lexilogos.com/etymologie.htm) page (with access to some of the [*FEW*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/) and [*PIE*](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/Fr.html) related material, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the kind of thing you are looking for:

[Claude Gruaz](http://www.lambert-lucas.com/disfa-dictionnaire-synchronique) (2008). *Dictionnaire synchronique des familles dérivationnelles de mots français*, Editions Lambert-Lucas.